# WHERE IN performance hit

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016, execution-plan

I got send a SQL query with the question why it is running poorly. They claim the query does not have any performance issues with their other clients who have a similar dataset and blame the performance issues on the fact that we are running SQL 2016...

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
    t.ID_, 
    t.EXECUTION_ID_,    
    t.PROC_INST_ID_,      
    <...snip...>
    t.TENANT_ID_,    
    e.business_key_, 
    wd.def_key
FROM ACT_RU_TASK t
LEFT JOIN ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK link ON (t.id_=link.task_id_ AND link.type_='candidate')
LEFT JOIN ACT_RU_EXECUTION e ON e.proc_inst_id_ = t.proc_inst_id_ AND e.parent_id_ IS NULL
LEFT JOIN UF_WORKFLOW_INSTANCE wi ON e.proc_inst_id_=wi.process_instance
LEFT JOIN UF_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION wd ON wd.id=wi.workflow_definition_fk
WHERE 
    link.group_id_ IN ( 
       <...12 strings here...>
    )
ORDER BY t.CREATE_TIME_ DESC
```

The query as is runs with the statistics below

`SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 3813 ms,  elapsed time = 4148 ms.`

If we remove the "WHERE ... IN"-clause

`(3809 rows affected) SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 250 ms,  elapsed time = 388 ms.`

Is it normal that a WHERE ... IN clause can cause this much of a performance hit? The estimated and actual execution plan see way off too.

**estimated execution plan**
[image: estimated execution plan]

**actual execution plan**
[image: actual execution plan]

Comment: Can you give us a "pastetheplan" representation of your problem ?
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Looking at the actual plan the problem doesn't seem to be the IN statemen. Instead the costanct scan + compute scalar is taking 3.66s out of the total 3.717s. THe estimation of the constant is way off, returning 1486 instead of expected 1. Not possible to see way in a screenshot. Please use pastethe plan as Hybris95 is suggesting.

Comment: *`.. LEFT JOIN ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK link ON .. WHERE link.group_id_ IN ( ..`* - replace this LEFT JOIN with INNER, or move the condition to ON clause (depends on needed logic).

Comment: @PeterÅ https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyfdXnecF

Comment: Unfortunately the execution plan did help that much. I did did into the XML and the compute scalar is using function GetRangeThroughConvert() on column .[dbo].[ACT_RU_EXECUTION].[PROC_INST_ID_]. Can it be some data type mismatch between that columns and one of the one that it join to? Doesn't explain why this is slow at you but not other clients. Same goes with the note from @Akina about the use on left join. Only thing that comes to mind is that this is then data related.

Comment: My "note" is not related to the performance. I point you to the fact that your query is logically incorrect and provide the way to fix this.

Comment: @PeterÅ Thank you for your feedback Peter. I ran the same query on their test database and there it was way quick, but I contributed that to the fact that this database is like 90% smaller. I checked the execution plan there and it did not need the GetRangeThroughConvert function. Could it be that they made an incorrect index in production? I doubt they made one in test...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Peter noted, the predicate where you `LEFT JOIN` to `UF_WORKFLOW_INSTANCE.process_instance` on `ACT_RU_EXECUTION.proc_inst_id_` is showing an implicit conversion happening in the execution plan:

> [mydatabase].[dbo].[ACT_RU_EXECUTION].[PROC_INST_ID_] as [e].[PROC_INST_ID_]=**CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(64)**,[mydatabase].[dbo].[uf_workflow_instance].[process_instance] as [wi].[process_instance],0).

This is indicative of a potential cause of your cardinality estimate issue. The other clients might have the same root *issue* in their execution plans too but have different data distributions that aren't resulting in the same cardinality estimate issue as a result.

If you materialize `UF_WORKFLOW_INSTANCE` to a temp table first and cast the `process_instance` field to `NVARCHAR(64)` when you insert it into the temp table, then join to that temp table instead, does the performance get better again (even with the `IN` clause in your query still)?

Comment: I did what you suggested and now the query runs in 174 ms. Thanks alot!

Comment: @MeMario great, no problem! BTW I wrote this answer in haste, I'll update it with some more information when I get a chance later. But I'd recommend, if possible, changing your data types in the root tables themselves to match so you don't have this issue other places you join to those tables. It seems like one field is of `NVARCHAR` type and I'd assume the other field (`process_instance`) is defined as a `VARCHAR` or some other text-based data type.